# Comparing two values from the same select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select query which selects all products from my inventory table and joins them with two other tables (tables l_products and a_products)

```
SELECT 
i.*, 
b.title, 
ROUND((i.price/100*80) - l.price,2)      AS margin, 
l.price                                  AS l_price, 
a.price                                  AS a_price, 
ROUND((a.price/100*80) - l.price, 2)     AS l_margin 

FROM inventory i 
LEFT JOIN products    b ON i.id  = b.id 
LEFT JOIN a_products  a ON i.id  = a.id 
LEFT JOIN l_products  l ON i.id  = l.id 

WHERE 
a.condition LIKE IF(i.condition = 'New', 'New%', 'Used%') 
AND l.condition LIKE IF(i.condition = 'New', 'New%', 'Used%')
```

This select query will normally give me a table such as...

```
id,        title, condition, margin, l_price, a_price ...
001-new    ...    new        10      20       10       
001-used   ...    used       10      25       20
002....
```

Now I need a condition in the query which will ignore all used products that are more expensive (have a higher a_price) than their 'new' counterparts, such as in the example above you can see that 001-used has a higher a_price than 001-new.

How can I achieve this with out having to resolve to using php

Answer (score 0):

`FULL JOIN` this query with it self on a column which has a uniquely same value for each id prefix.

You may achieve this effect by adding another field to your `SELECT` call which produces same unique value for 001-new and 001-used, 002-new and 002-used...

Such value generation can be done by defining your own SQL Routine to extract first 3 characters from a column.